# taxonomy manager

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to allow users to add taxonomy terms for a particular taxonomy.
I added a menu item to link to the taxonomy manager. The problem is -

1. I'm not able to restrict the user to add terms to only one taxonomy (based on his role).
2. Alternatively, I tried to hide "switch vocabulary" drop down by editing the theme css (not module css. I want the behavior to be same even after module updates). That didn't work either.

Any suggestions on -

1. how to give users access to add taxonomy terms. (or)
2. restrict access in taxonomy manager (or)

Thanks

Comment: are you linking these tax terms to nodes?

Comment: While creating nodes, yes. But not while creating the terms. Does that make sense ??

Comment: did you try my 2nd answer? (the module)

Comment: I did. The module didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a **Term Reference** field to your node with **auto complete widget**

When you type something that is not in the vocabulary, it will auto create/add it to your vocabulary as a new tax term when you hit save node.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to separate out adding terms/adding nodes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Vocabulary Permissions Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/vppr) module.

> You have set up some vocabularies (with some terms) like Color (Red,
>   Green, Blue) and Shape (Toroid, Cube, Sphere). Maybe you even have a
>   vocabulary that controls who can view a specific node (with terms)
>   like Access control (Editors, Colleagues, World). Here comes trouble:
>   your precious editors want to add more Colors, or reorder the terms of
>   the Shape vocabulary (probably they want to see Sphere before Cube,
>   who knows,) and you do NOT want to grant your editors the administer
>   taxonomy permission, as it grants too much power (and that implies too
>   much sharing of responsibility). Without this permission they were NOT
>   able to do the mentioned tricks: adding terms to a vocabulary but not
>   to another, reordering/editing terms of a vocabulary but not
>   another's, etc.

Looks like this does exactly what you need.